# Tomcat and Eclipse HTTP Status 500 missing ResourceBundle

Tags: eclipse, http, tomcat, resourcebundle

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

The title and the screenshots pretty much says it all...

Answer (score 0):

The temporary solutin was to put the *.properties-files in the class-directory. Not pretty but it works for now.